# Java - array's index out of bounds when its not?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem in the code below:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int[] map = new int[100 * 100];
        System.out.println("Works : " + map[10 * 100 + 5]);
        System.out.println("Works? : " + map[99 * 100 + 99]);
        System.out.println("Works?! : " + map[20 * 100 + 100]);
        //System.out.println("And this?? : " + map[99 * 100 + 100]);
    }
}
```

As you can see the last line (the comment) doesn't work; it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

But I dont get it; it should be in the array's bounds. The array's size is `100*100` so `99 * 100 + 100 = 100*100` so index `100*100` is in the array.

I've already fixed the problem; I would just like to know why I get an exception on the above line.

Link to code: http://ideone.com/ydgU9s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws that exception because the index of an array are from `0` to `length -1`.

So if you declared it to have a length of 100*100, the indexes are from `0` to `100*100 -1`.

And what you tried:

```
map[99 * 100 + 100]
```

is equal to

```
map[100*100]
```

which cannot be accesed.

Comment: ok too many comments.. yeah that's what i thought, just wanted to be sure, thanks and accepted :D  in 9 minutes

Answer (score 1):

[Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) are 0 base indexed.

So you can access the elements in map from index `0` to `map.length - 1`.

I.e : `map[0]` to `map[100*100-1]`

Or `99 * 100 + 100 = 10000 > 9999`, that's why you got an `IOOBE`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access Map[10000]. Array index starts with 0 , so the array with size 10,000 means 0 to 9999.